# Parsing multiple .log files to get a string name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

`File1.log`:

```
Result for scripts as follows {"Script 1"=>{"expected"=>"Pass", "actual"=>"Pass", "result"=>true}, 
"Script 2"=>{"expected"=>"Fail", "actual"=>"Pass", "result"=>false}
-----
-----
-----
-----
Result for scripts as follows {"Script 3"=>{"expected"=>"Pass", "actual"=>"Pass", "result"=>true}, "Script 4"=>{"expected"=>"Fail", "actual"=>"Pass", "result"=>false}
```

`File2.log`:

```
Result for scripts as follows {"Script 1"=>{"expected"=>"Pass", "actual"=>"Pass", "result"=>true}, "Script 2"=>{"expected"=>"Pass", "actual"=>"Pass", "result"=>true}
```

I will have to parse the `.log` files which will contain multiple lines and get the above given lines alone.

The only thing common to be used to get this is the first text: `Result for scripts as follows`.

Any suggestions to solve this using Ruby or any powershell commands?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you need to traverse each log file line by line, perform a pattern match and print the results.

The below code should solve your problem

```
# my log files are in my current working directory

log_files = Dir["./*.log"]
false_matches = []
log_files.each do |x|
  puts "\n#{x}\n==========\n"
  f = File.open(x,"r")
  f.each_line do |line|
    false_matches.push(line.scan(/"Script \d*"=>{"expected"=>".{4}", "actual"=>".{4}", "result"=>false/))

  end
  puts "\n"
  f.close()
end

false_matches.each do |x| 
  unless x.length == 0
    puts x[0].scan(/Script \d*/)
  end
end
```

Comment: I would have to take the line which contains only this result with false
Eg Inputs:
Result for script-1 as follows {"Script "=>{"expected"=>"Pass", "actual"=>"Pass", "result"=>true}, "Script 4"=>{"expected"=>"Fail", "actual"=>"Pass", "result"=>false}
Result for script-2 as follows {"Script 3"=>{"expected"=>"Pass", "actual"=>"Pass", "result"=>true}, "Script 4"=>{"expected"=>"Fail", "actual"=>"Pass", "result"=>true}

When I run my code I should be getting the script number for which I have result as false
Expected Output:
Script-1

Comment: Code updated as per expected output. Question was missing the expected output

Comment: What if the actual and expected are dynamic strings?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?